# Select thin line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

All!

There are lines (path), which i can select. width=1(no change).
There are difficulties when i try select line, difficult to get the mouse on the line.

How can I select a thin line easier (more convenient), without changing its width?

Thanks

```js
d3.select("path")
  //select line use click
  .on("click", function(d){
    var flag = d3.select(this).classed("selected");
  
    d3.select(this).classed("selected", !flag);
  });
```

```css
svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}

path.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #333;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    cursor: default;
}
path.link:hover, path.link.selected {
    stroke: rgb(94, 196, 204);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg>
  <path class="link" d="M550,100L545,100L545,100L545,30L665,30L665,40"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase **all** your question?

Comment: @Suren Srapyan, your edit brings no improvement at all.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes it is a minor edit, but it can make the code a bit readable. I don't say that it changes the state of the question

Comment: Sorry! I update post and add comment in code.

Comment: create a new set of lines in the same positions as your current ones but with a thicker width and set them to transparent : opacity=0; That should be a good enough work around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different solutions for your problem, the simplest one being creating a transparent line, thicker than the visible one, which will catch the mouse events:

```js
d3.select(".transparent").on("mouseover", function(){
    d3.select(".link").style("stroke", "rgb(94, 196, 204)");
}).on("mouseout", function(){
    d3.select(".link").style("stroke", "#333")
});
```

```css
svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}

path.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #333;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    cursor: default;
}

path.transparent {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width:10px;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <path class="link" d="M550,100L545,100L545,100L545,30L665,30L665,40" transform="translate(-400,0)"></path>
  <path class="transparent" d="M550,100L545,100L545,100L545,30L665,30L665,40" transform="translate(-400,0)"></path>
</svg>
```